# Using a percent to find a partial python

Tags: python-2.7, percentage

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out a puzzle that I'm working on. 
The idea is to find the remaining total when subtracting the percentage.

This should be a fairly simple exercise but for one reason or another I'm having difficulty finding a result that works properly.

Please forgive my formatting, this is my first post.

```
from math import floor  
def compute_active_users(n, b):  
    x = float(b)/float(n) * 100  
    x = x * 100  
    return floor((n - x))  

print '-' * 25  
print compute_active_users(1000,25) # Expected output: ------- 750  
print '-' * 25  
print compute_active_users(835,17) # Expected output: ------- 693  
print '-' * 25  


Results:  
-------------------------  
750.0  
-------------------------  
631.0  
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
def compute_active_users(n, b):
    return n * (1 - b / 100.)
```

Here:

- `b / 100.` converts the percentage into a *fraction*.
- `1 - ...` computes the *remaining* fraction.
- `n * ...` computes the remaining *number of users*.

Note that this will happily return a fractional number of users, so you may want to add rounding as the final step.